# List Files from Google Drive without login

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been looking at the Google Drive API for a while now. I have a folder publicly shared that I can look at without being logged in to anything with the host URL in the details of the shared folder. So I know that you can see these files without Oauth or any other authentication. is there a way to do this with the API so that I can get the files formatted the way I want and possibly use the description that I have added to the file? Basically this will show on a website and I do not want people visiting the site to have to go through the Oauth process. I just want a list of files to show up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a similar design. My reading of the docs says the API requires login. So unless you resort to page scraping, you'll need to go through the oauth.

Presumably you have a dedicated account where the files are stored. You've registered a client app and a redirect url, and obtained the necessary keys. (The overview is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server).) Now, if I understand correctly, you have to then create a Google_Client object, configure it, and call `createAuthUrl` to get the authorization URL.

When you browse to authorization URL, you will have to log in to the account where your files are stored -- just this once. After a successful login, you are redirected to your redirect_url with a query string parameter: `code`. This is the authorization code that you use to get the *refresh token* for you app. Doc is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server). You will get the refresh token just once, save it, and use it each time to get a session (access) token.

I think the authorization is the only really complicated part of the drive API, so once you're past this it should be smoother.